# Count n_distinct with a condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe:

```
df<-data.frame(Name= c(rep("A",3), rep("B",5)), Month = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,3,3), Volume = c(50,0,50,50,50,50,50,50))
```

and I would like to update a column "Count" to represent the number of unique Months per Name:

```
df<-df%>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(Count = n_distinct(Month))
```

However, how can I add a filter such that I only count Months whose corresponding Value > 0? This is my desired output:

```
df<-data.frame(Name= c(rep("A",3), rep("B",5)), Month = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,3,3), Volume = c(50,0,50,50,50,50,50,50), Count = c(2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Or `mutate(Count = n_distinct(Month[Volume>0]))`

Comment: Thanks @AndrewGustar! If you write this as an answer, I will happily accept as it required minimal change to my current code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a condition to `Month`...

```
df <- df %>%
      group_by(Name) %>%
      mutate(Count = n_distinct(Month[Volume>0]))

df
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   Name [2]
    Name Month Volume Count
  <fctr> <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
1      A     1     50     2
2      A     2      0     2
3      A     3     50     2
4      B     1     50     3
5      B     2     50     3
6      B     3     50     3
7      B     3     50     3
8      B     3     50     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the `n_distinct` function, we can use the `duplicated` function as well as including `Volume > 0` in the logical expression:

```
df %>%
    group_by(Name) %>%
    mutate(Count = sum(!duplicated(Month) & Volume > 0)) # not duplicated, Volume > 0

    Name Month Volume Count
  <fctr> <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
1      A     1     50     2
2      A     2      0     2
3      A     3     50     2
4      B     1     50     3
5      B     2     50     3
6      B     3     50     3
7      B     3     50     3
8      B     3     50     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df%>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(Count = n_unique(Month[Volume >0]))
```

Comment: length gives me the total number of entries, not the number of unique entries. However, if I use n_distinct instead of length, I get the output I want!